# Expand text in a JavaFX component

Tags: java, javafx

I have a String (about a paragraph long, contains newlines and unicode) that I'm displaying in a JavaFX component (Right now a large Label but changing specific implementation is an option), and when a user clicks on a word, I want that word to be "expanded" ("word" -> "w o r d")

(actually, this isn't exactly true, I want to pass the word to a more complicated function and use the result, but what the function is shouldn't matter)

I could generate html and use that, but all the ways to change text by clicking on it in html seem to require javascript, and I don't know how well java handles embedded js.

I could generate a bunch of Labels, one for each word, and write an onClick listener, but the spacing would probably get screwed up.

I could use one Label and use an onClick listener and try to figure out what word is being clicked on using the mouseX and mouseY, but that's pretty tricky and I'd like to know if there are better solutions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried putting `Text` elements into a [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html)? That way you can easily detect input events on the individual text objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using a collection of `Text` objects in a `TextFlow`. Doing this enables you to register a mouse handler directly on each text object. This also sets a CSS pseudoclass on the text object, so you can easily change the style of the expanded word with a CSS stylesheet.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExpandingTextExample extends Application {

    // The following text is taken from the "JavaFX CSS Reference Guide":
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html 

    private static final String text = "Never has styling a Java UI been easier than "
            + "with JavaFX and Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). "
            + "Going from one theme to another, or "
            + "customizing the look of just one control, "
            + "can all be done through CSS. To the novice, "
            + "this may be unfamiliar territory; "
            + "but the learning curve is not that great. "
            + "Give CSS styling a try and the benefits will soon be apparent. "
            + "You can also split the design and development workflow, or "
            + "defer design until later in the project. "
            + "Up to the last minute changes, and even post-deployment "
            + "changes, in the UI's look can be achieved through JavaFX CSS. "
            + "\n"
            + "The structure of this document is as follows. "
            + "First, there is a description of all "
            + "value types for JavaFX CSS properties. "
            + "Where appropriate, this includes a grammar "
            + "for the syntax of values of that type. "
            + "Then, for each scene‑graph node that supports CSS styles, "
            + "a table is given that lists the properties that are supported, "
            + "along with type and semantic information. "
            + "The pseudo‑classes for each class are also given. "
            + "The description of CSS properties continues for the controls. "
            + "For each control, the substructure of that control's skin is given, "
            + "along with the style‑class names for the Region "
            + "objects that implement that substructure." ;

    private static final String NBSP = "\u2007" ;

    private final PseudoClass expanded = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("expanded");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
        flow.setLineSpacing(5);
        Stream.of(words)
            .map(s -> s.concat(" "))
            .map(Text::new)
            .peek(text -> text.getStyleClass().add("word"))
            .peek(text -> text.setOnMousePressed(event -> expand(text)))
            .forEach(flow.getChildren()::add);

        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        scroller.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroller.setContent(flow);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scroller, 600, 400);

        scene.getStylesheets().add("expanding-text.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void expand(Text text) {
        if (text.getPseudoClassStates().contains(expanded)) { //collapse:
            String[] letters = text.getText().split(NBSP);
            StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
            Stream.of(letters).forEach(newText::append);
            text.setText(newText.toString());
            text.pseudoClassStateChanged(expanded, false);
        } else {
            String[] letters = text.getText().split("");
            text.setText(String.join(NBSP, letters));
            text.pseudoClassStateChanged(expanded, true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The stylesheet is expanding-text.css:

```
.word:expanded {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt ;
    -fx-font-weight: bold ;
}
```

Here is a screenshot from startup:

[image]

and this is after clicking on the first word of each sentence in the first paragraph:

[image]